# Can't unmount USB drive

Tags: 15.10, usb-drive, unmount

If i try unmount usb drive i see this error.

```
Error unmounting /dev/sdb1: Command-line `umount  "/media/michal/MUZA"' exited with non-zero exit status 32 umount: /media/michal/MUZA: not mounted
```

Comment: Is the USB drive mounted at the time you try to umount it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error points to it not being mounted .. maybe its not mounted at that point. Try running `gparted` and switch to the usb then look at Mount Point and check where and if its mounted

Or you can type in terminal:

```
mount | grep ^'/dev/sdb1'
```

it should return

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/michal/MUZA type .....
```

if it is mounted .. or a different path if it is mounted somewhere else

Just verified .. had a USB  with the label CD_ROM and it mounted as /media/username/CD_ROM .. I removed the label and now it mounts with UUID.

If you want it to be mounted at /media/michal/MUZA you will need to change/add the MUZA label to the drive.

I was able to label it in Ubuntu using gparted .. I just went to the USB drive then .. if its mounted I right clicked and unmounted it then I right clicked again and chose Label File System .. Put in the name (name cant have any spaces in it... if you want spaces you need to use an underscore or dash) After I had the name I clicked on the green check mark to apply the settings . Once I did that for some reason I couldn't mount it but then I put it in my Windows machine .. it seemed fine and when I plugged it back in to Ubuntu it mounted as my Label and worked

If you run into a situation where you did get it to label but now instead of the label MUZA it is mounting it as MUZA2 then remove the USB and check the /media/michal folder and see if there is a left over MUZA folder in there. If so you will have to run a terminal and type

```
sudo rm -r -f /media/michal/MUZA
```

That should remove the folder and the next time you plug in your USB it should mount as the label without the 2 at the end.

Comment: Return this.
/dev/sdb1 on /media/michal/36EEC75002B2B4B8 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)

This usb drive before name "MUZA" now it is format to ntfs (before fat)

Comment: Ok so its not mounted as MUZA its using the UUID. Do you have it set to mount or is it automatic when you plug it in?

Comment: This usb drive before name "MUZA" now it is format to ntfs (before fat) .
Automatic mount

Comment: it probably doesn't have a label anymore .. if you format it again and label it MUZA i believe it will mount as MUZA instead of the UUID

Comment: unfortunately it does not work

Comment: I just tested to verify .. yes it does work. I stuck the USB into my windows machine .. right clicked on the USB in file manager then chose properties and put in the label there .. then closed properties and ejected the drive .. then when I put it into Ubuntu it mounted as /media/username/CD_ROM instead of the UUID

Comment: I tried using Ubuntu to label it but something seems to have gone wrong so  I probably did it wrong .. it was very easy though if you have a Windows machine that you can put the USB in and change it in the properties screen

Comment: weird thing is .. i put it in my windows machine to check if it was labeled correctly and it seemed to be so i took it out and plugged it back into Ubuntu and it mounted as labeled again.. so once its labeled .. remove it from the USB port then try plugging it back in... it should mount as labeled

Comment: I try in windows label name is ok but "name" is bad

Comment: This is screenshot [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B19MBfTE0qSVTVRTYkItd1NKUlE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: did you label it MUZA and it is mounting as MUZA2? is that the problem now?

Comment: Yes this is problem now

Comment: i updated my answer to try to help you resolve that issue. it is probably a left over folder in the /media/michal  directory and I explain how to remove it .. just make sure when you check to see if the MUZA folder exists that your drive isnt actually plugged in .. so you aren't trying to delete the actual real share

Comment: glad to hear :)