# Can't unmount USB drive. Error messages say it's not mounted

Tags: usb-drive, unmount

I have a problem with my USB drives. I have two drives, one partition each. One is EXT4, the other FAT32. I formatted both with Ubuntu itself. They both seem "known good."

If I plug both drives in, both are recognized, and both work.

But when I try, from Nautilus, to unmount sdb1, I receive an error message:

> Error unmounting /dev/sdb1: not mounted.

And yet Nautilus shows it as mounted, and I can see and work with its contents. The "Disks" app also shows it as mounted.

"Disks" shows both drives. But trying to unmount sdb1 results in a similar "disk not mounted" error message, plus a parenthetical "udisks-error-quark, 0."

Entering `umount /dev/sdb1` in the terminal results in this error message:

```
Error unmounting block device 8:17. GDBus. Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error unmounting /dev/sdb1: not mounted.
```

This behavior is the same regardless of which of my two drives is sda and which sdb. And which USB ports the devices are plugged into doesn't matter either. The problem is not a result of overheating; even from a "cold start" we see the same behavior.

Running `df -hT` in the terminal shows both sda1 and sdb1.

Sda1 unmounts fine.

Even when sda1 is unmounted, the problem with sdb1 persists.

Both drives are mounted on `/media/jswami`. One drive is `/media/jswami/KINGSTON15`, the other `/media/jswami/JSbackup1`.

Trying

```
umount /media/jswami/KINGSTON15
```

gives the same result as `umount /dev/sdb1`.

```
$ mount | grep /dev/sd

/dev/sdb1 on /media/jswami/KINGSTON15 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)

/dev/sda1 on /media/jswami/JSbackup1 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uhelper=udisks2)
```

I've looked here -- [Can't unmount USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767647/cant-unmount-usb-drive) -- but I didn't see a solution for me.

Ubuntu 20.04, upgraded from previous versions.
IBM ThinkPad X1-Carbon

Any advice?

---

Thought I had it solved. There was a permissions issue. The permissions for one of the drives were assigned to "root." And reassigning them to "Me" seemed at first to solve the problem -- but, no, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the existing mount points. That solved the problem.